# bubbles on acryllic shower walls and caulking

Tags: shower, installation

newly installed shower stall has two acryllic walls that were affixed to the proper mold resistent dry wall material.  when the shower walls heat up they bubble out in a couple of places apparently where glue was not applied. not a huge aesthestic issue but i am concerned about the bubbling over time.  will it lead to leaks where the acryllic is silliconed to the frame/wall?

Secondly, my contractor applied sillicone to the outer frame and not the inside of the shower.  this seems wrong to me in that water and soap scum could sit within the frame???

Comment: Clear, focused pictures will help us assess the situation. Please [edit] them into your question.